No web support for AvaloniaInside.Shell?
I am testing the AvaloniaInside.Shell package in a new app and it works well, however I have not been able to run the web application, it only raises the server with the classic "Powered by
Avalonia UI" without further ado.
In the description of the library there is no reference or web examples either.
using System.Runtime.Versioning;
using AchievableSavings;
using Avalonia;
using Avalonia.Browser;
using Avalonia.ReactiveUI;
using AvaloniaInside.Shell;

[assembly: SupportedOSPlatform("browser")]

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildAvaloniaApp()
            .UseReactiveUI()
            .UseShell()
            .StartBrowserAppAsync("out");
    }

    public static AppBuilder BuildAvaloniaApp()
    {
        return AppBuilder.Configure<App>();
    }
}

enter image description here
Replicate desktop content on the web.
